# Привязка к ComboBox.SelectedItem не отрабатывает без смены фокуса

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Сделал такую привязку:

```
cbSaveResultMode.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedItem), _configViewModel, nameof(_configViewModel.ImageSaveMode), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Она работает, но работает тогда, когда я выбрал элемент и поменял фокус на другой контрол.

Подскажите, можно ли это как-то поправить?

Comment: Можно, WPF xD. А если серьезно, попробуйте протестить `SelectedValue` или `SelectedIndex`. Если не сработает, то делайте через обработчик события. Это все-таки Winforms, и привязки там работают весьма криво.

Comment: Лучше думаю клнечно через обработчик события. Так надёжнее

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Что является источником данных? Какой именно тип у свойства?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Enum и там на комбобокс сбинжена коллекция этих Enum'ов

Comment: Коллекция - BindingList?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, но я в ней никаких изменений не произвожу. Привязал и хочу получать текущий элемент.